# address validation using google maps

Tags: meteor, maps

I'm trying to do address validation using google api within a Meteor Platform. What's the best way to achieve that?

I tried [this](http://jsfiddle.net/d4rkxb2z/) but I'm facing a lot of trouble. Is there a more structured way to do that in Meteor?

```
<div class="page">
    <div id="main">
        <form id="MyForm" name="MyForm" action="form.html">
            <div id="map_canvas" style="float: right; height: 200px; width: 400px;"></div>
            <div>
                <label for="Name">
                    Name</label>
                <input id="Name" name="Name" type="text" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="FullAddress">
                    Address</label>
                <textarea id="FullAddress" name="FullAddress" cols="40" rows="5" class="fulladdressvalidator"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input id="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" type="button" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // The following code show execute only after the page is fully loaded
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($('#MyForm').exists()) {

            // Enable jQuery Validation for the form
            $("#MyForm").validate({ onkeyup: false });

            // Add validation rules to the FullAddress field
            $("#FullAddress").rules("add", {
                fulladdress: true,
                required: true,
                messages: {
                    fulladdress: "Google cannot locate this address."
                }
            });

            // This function will be executed when the form is submitted
            function FormSubmit() {
                $.submitForm = true;
                if (!$('#MyForm').valid()) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    if ($("#FullAddress").data("IsChecking") == true) {
                        $("#FullAddress").data("SubmitForm", true);
                        return false;
                    }

                    alert('Form Valid!  Submit!');
                    // return true;   // Uncomment to submit the form.
                    return false;     // Supress the form submission for test purpose.

                }
            }

            // Attach the FormSubmit function to the Submit button
            if ($('#Submit').exists()) {
                $("#Submit").click(FormSubmit);
            }

            // Execute the ForumSubmit function when the form is submitted
            $('#MyForm').submit(FormSubmit);
        }
    });

    // Create a jQuery exists method
    jQuery.fn.exists = function () { return jQuery(this).length > 0; }

    // Position the Google Map
    function Map(elementId, geolocation) {
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 13,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(elementId), myOptions);
        map.setCenter(geolocation);
    }

    // FullAddress jQuery Validator
    function FullAddressValidator(value, element, paras) {

        // Convert the value variable into something a bit more descriptive
        var CurrentAddress = value;

        // If the address is blank, then this is for the required validator to deal with.
        if (value.length == 0) {
            return true;
        }

        // If we've already validated this address, then just return the previous result
        if ($(element).data("LastAddressValidated") == CurrentAddress) {
            return $(element).data("IsValid");
        }

        // We have a new address to validate, set the IsChecking flag to true and set the LastAddressValidated to the CurrentAddress
        $(element).data("IsChecking", true);
        $(element).data("LastAddressValidated", CurrentAddress);

        // Google Maps doesn't like line-breaks, remove them
        CurrentAddress = CurrentAddress.replace(/\n/g, "");

        // Create a new Google geocoder
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': CurrentAddress }, function (results, status) {

            // The code below only gets run after a successful Google service call has completed.
            // Because this is an asynchronous call, the validator has already returned a 'true' result
            // to supress an error message and then cancelled the form submission.  The code below
            // needs to fetch the true validation from the Google service and then re-execute the
            // jQuery form validator to display the error message.  Futhermore, if the form was
            // being submitted, the code below needs to resume that submit.

            // Google reported a valid geocoded address
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                // Get the formatted Google result
                var address = results[0].formatted_address;

                // Count the commas in the fomatted address.
                // This doesn't look great, but it helps us understand how specific the geocoded address
                // is.  For example, "CA" will geocde to "California, USA".
                numCommas = address.match(/,/g).length;

                // A full street address will have at least 3 commas.  Alternate techniques involve
                // fetching the address_components returned by Google Maps.  That code looks even more ugly.
                if (numCommas >= 3) {

                    // Replace the first comma found with a line-break
                    address = address.replace(/, /, "\n");

                    // Remove USA from the address (remove this, if this is important to you)
                    address = address.replace(/, USA$/, "");

                    // Check for the map_canvas, if it exists then position the Google Map
                    if ($("#map_canvas").exists()) {
                        $("#map_canvas").show();
                        Map("map_canvas", results[0].geometry.location);
                    }

                    // Set the textarea value to the geocoded address
                    $(element).val(address);

                    // Cache this latest result
                    $(element).data("LastAddressValidated", address);

                    // We have a valid geocoded address
                    $(element).data("IsValid", true);
                } else {
                    // Google Maps was able to geocode the address, but it wasn't specific
                    // enough (not enough commas) to be a valid street address.
                    $(element).data("IsValid", false);
                }

                // Otherwise the address is invalid
            } else {
                $(element).data("IsValid", false);
            }

            // We're no longer in the midst of validating
            $(element).data("IsChecking", false);

            // Get the parent form element for this address field
            var form = $(element).parents('form:first');

            // This code is being run after the validation for this field,
            // if the form was being submitted before this validtor was
            // called then we need to re-submit the form.
            if ($(element).data("SubmitForm") == true) {
                form.submit();
            } else {
                // Re-validate this property so we can return the result.
                form.validate().element(element);
            }
        });

        // The FullAddress validator always returns 'true' when initially called.
        // The true result will be return later by the geocode function (above)
        return true;
    }

    // Define a new jQuery Validator method
    $.validator.addMethod("fulladdress", FullAddressValidator);
</script>
```

Comment: I'm no expert in Meteor but there are better ways to validate an address than with the google service (which is actually just designed to show you the approximate location of any address, real or contrived). I work for SmartyStreets, a true address verification/validation provider. We've got a jquery plugin you can plop down on your HTML page: https://smartystreets.com/docs/plugin

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this in a Meteor way you should put your html into a template:

```
<template name="tplExample">
  <div class="page">
    {{somedata}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Then you can write your events and helpers for this template in a .js file:

```
Template['tplExample'].events({
 //this scopes just elements from tplExample
 "submit #Myform": function(e){/*handle the event*/ }
 })


Template['tplExample'].rendered = function(){
    // The following code show execute only after the page is fully loaded
   }


Template['tplExample'].helpers({
 //this scopes just elements from tplExample
 some_data: function(){ /*handle data validation*/}
 })
```

Take a look here https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/a-look-at-a-meteor-template/